# Apart from using >>>Import this to derive the Zen of Python , is there any other way?

Tags: python

Apart from using (>>>Import this )to derive the Zen of Python , is there any other way  to derive the Zen of Python..

Comment: PEP 20 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ or the obfuscated source code, but why?

Comment: I was working on the presentation to switch from Java scripting to Python scripting and needed some info around for the initial slides in my presentation. I was talking about the PEP 20..